# SequelizeJS N:M Check associations is not working as mentioned in the docs

Tags: javascript, node.js, orm, sequelize.js

This example from sequelizeJS docs is not working as mentioned. Here is the [link](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/tutorial/associations.html#check-associations).

```
// check if all associated objects are as expected:
// let's assume we have already a project and two users
project.setUsers([user1, user2]).then(() => {
  return project.hasUsers([user1]);
}).then(result => {
// result would be false // For me it is returning true
   return project.hasUsers([user1, user2]);
}).then(result => {
// result would be true
})
```

**To reproduce**

Assume a project as 2 users user1, user2. ***hasUsers()*** Returns true instead of false for this scenario.

```
project.hasUsers([user1]); // => returns true instead of false
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The example in the docs was a typo error. It is now fixed reference [link](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/commit/bf7a55babf4a8aacbf05c30c3ac6ef549fe14ffa)